# Mass and the dispersion relation

Tags: special-relativity, mass

The relativistic **dispersion relation** states:

\begin{equation}
\frac{E^{2}}{c^{2}}=m_{0}^{2} c^{2}+p^{2}
\end{equation}

Where $m_{0}$ is the rest mass.

I have heard that the **mass** ($m_{0}$ in this context) can be defined as *the gap of the dispersion relation*.

1. What is this gap?
2. Can you provide a 2D graphic showing this gap?

Answer (score 1):

Take $c=1$ and draw the $E$-vs-$p$ hyperbola. The gap is the gap between it and the origin (or between it and the line $E=0$); that distance in the energy-momentum plane is equal to $m_0$.

The physical significance of this gap is that a massive particle has a minimum nonzero energy, even when it has no momentum.

In my opinion, it’s better to think of the mass as the Lorentz-invariant length, in 4D Minkowski space, of the energy-momentum four-vector $(E,p_x,p_y,p_z)$, namely

$$m_0=\sqrt{E^2-p_x^2-p_y^2-p_z^2},$$

in units where $c=1$. All inertial observers, with various relative velocities, agree on the value of this 4D length, even though they do not agree on the values of the components $E$, $p_x$, $p_y$, and $p_z$. Many quantities in Relativity are relative (i.e., frame-dependent), but some are absolute (frame-independent), and mass is one if them.

Comment: The GAP is the GAP between it and the origin or between a horizontal line representing the mass $m_{0}$?

Comment: The origin. Why are you capitalizing GAP?

Comment: I edited my answer to mention that you can also consider the gap to be between the hyperbola and the line $E=0$.

Comment: I also added the physical significance.

Comment: The mobile corrector capitalizes it... It's now corrected. Thank you for the answer, is illustrative.